# AWS Systems Manager API call in Postman gives 'Validation Error'

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, aws-api-gateway, rest, aws-ssm

I am using AWS Systems Manager to restart EC2 instances. When I setup a document (for Automation Execution) and try to execute a POST API call to

https://ssm.us-east-1.amazonaws.com?Action=StartAutomationExecution

with headers similar to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_StartAutomationExecution.html#API_StartAutomationExecution_Examples

and a body of

```
{
    "DocumentName": "AWS-StartEC2Instance",
    "Parameters": {
        "InstanceId": [
            "i-0fa94145b40e8b240"
        ]
    }
}
```

I get the error,

```
{
    "Error": {
        "Code": "ValidationError",
        "Message": "1 validation error detected: Value null at 'documentName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null.",
        "Type": "Sender"
    },
    "RequestId": "cbd70ca6-d176-4c80-bf96-56cba8333d8d"
}
```

I have given my documentName and instance ID in the body of my API request. Not sure why this error keeps coming.

Any suggestions ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, looks like https://ssm.us-east-1.amazonaws.com?Action=StartAutomationExecution with the request parameter "Action=StartAutomationExecution" does not work (atleast in Postman). Remove that.

Instead adding the headers "X-Amz-Target: AmazonSSM.StartAutomationExecution" and "Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1", did the trick